# Crystal Reports erroring out because of ampersands in parameter

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports

Parameters being sent to Crystal with an ampersand for multiple values. I need to know how to remove the ampersands and replace them with commas. Here is an example of what I am receiving from the application,

```
red&blue&green&white&
```

and so on.

I need that to come across as

```
red,blue,green,white,.
```

I have tried the replace function, but I am unable to get it done.

Comment: Please post your function code, and let's find out what is causing it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Most programming languages (you don't specify yours) have a Replace() function.